# Laravel access uploaded file

Tags: php, laravel

I've successfully uploaded an image like this:

```
Storage::put($path,$request->file($name));
```

But how could I acces this right now? The file is in 
`storage/app/employees/3/profile.`

When I go to `.dev/storage/app/employees/3/profile/image.png` the route is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your image path will be

```
<img src="{{storage_path('app/employees/3/profile/image.png')}}">
```

Comment: Thanks! And how could I access this with an api?

Comment: if you are using api,you need to response full directory form your application,cause outside from your application,you can't access this method.